# sobre array por teclado

Tags: array, consola

Estoy intentando crear un array de 5 numeros, entre cero y cien, e imprimirlos por pantalla, llevo esto de código:
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

```
    InputStreamReader entrada = new InputStreamReader(System.in);/* creamos el objeto "ENTRADA" indicamos que la entrada de datos es la consola (System.ini)*/
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(entrada); /*indicamos que debe leer los datos introducidos en el objeto "ENTRADA"*/
```

/********************************************************************************************/

```
     Double[] arrayD;       /*creacion de arrayD tipo double*/
     arrayD = new Double[5]; /*asignacion del tamaño 5*/ 



        do {
     System.out.print("dame el PRIMER numero: ");           /*peticion de los 5 números*/
     arrayD[0] = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());         
        }while (arrayD[0] <0 || arrayD[0] >101);            /*repetición mientras no esté entre 1 y 100*/

        do {
     System.out.print("dame el SEGUNDO numero: ");
     arrayD[1] = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
        }while (arrayD[1] <0 || arrayD[1] >101);

     do {
     System.out.print("dame el TERCER numero: ");
     arrayD[2] = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
        }while (arrayD[2] <0 || arrayD[2] >101);

     do {
     System.out.print("dame el CUARTO numero: ");
     arrayD[3] = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
        }while (arrayD[3] <0 || arrayD[3] >101);

     do {
     System.out.print("dame el QUINTO numero: ");
     arrayD[4] = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
        }while (arrayD[4] <0 || arrayD[4] >101); /*exige que los números estén entre 0 y 100*/



     /*System.out.println(arrayD);*/<--esto no funciona, por qué?*/
     System.out.println(+arrayD[0] +"; "+arrayD[1] +"; "+arrayD[2]+"; "+arrayD[3]+"; "+arrayD[4]); /* TENGO QUE IMPRIMIRLOS ASI los números almacenados*/
```

/*LA PREGUNTA ES, PARA IMPRIMIR LOS NÚMEROS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para imprimir el arreglo en pantalla deberías hacerlo con un bucle `for` que recorra el arreglo en su totalidad. Esto se logra de la siguiente manera:

```
for(int i=0; i<arrayD.length; i++) System.out.println(arrayD[i]);
```

El nombre del arreglo (`arrayD`) es un puntero a un arreglo de, en este caso, objetos de tipo `Double`, por lo que la sentencia `System.out.println(arrayD);` no tiene sentido si lo que quieres obtener son los elementos del arreglo.

Te dejo el código corregido:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        InputStreamReader entrada = new InputStreamReader(System.in);/* creamos el objeto "ENTRADA" indicamos que la entrada de datos es la consola (System.ini)*/
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(entrada);
        
        Double[] arrayD;       /*creacion de arrayD tipo double*/
        arrayD = new Double[5]; /*asignacion del tamaño 5*/ 

        do
        {
            System.out.print("dame el PRIMER numero: ");           /*peticion de los 5 números*/
            arrayD[0] = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());         
        }
        while (arrayD[0] <0 || arrayD[0] >101);            /*repetición mientras no esté entre 1 y 100*/

        do
        {
            System.out.print("dame el SEGUNDO numero: ");
            arrayD[1] = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
        }
        while (arrayD[1] <0 || arrayD[1] >101);

         do
         {
             System.out.print("dame el TERCER numero: ");
             arrayD[2] = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
         }
         while (arrayD[2] <0 || arrayD[2] >101);

         do
         {
             System.out.print("dame el CUARTO numero: ");
             arrayD[3] = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
         }
         while (arrayD[3] <0 || arrayD[3] >101);

         do
         {
             System.out.print("dame el QUINTO numero: ");
             arrayD[4] = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
         }
         while (arrayD[4] <0 || arrayD[4] >101);
         
         for(int i=0; i<arrayD.length; i++) System.out.println(arrayD[i]); //Recorro el arreglo elemento por elemento y los imprimo en pantalla uno a la vez, uno debajo del otro.
    }
}
```

Y una corroboración de su funcionaimento:

[image: Funcionamiento del programa]

## Algo más...

Una buena práctica de programación en Java es, al menos, el manejo de funciones para no tener todo el programa en una sola función principal en una sola clase principal. El manejo de funciones y la programación orientada a objetos (**POO**) trae un sinfín de beneficios que pueden ayudarte a que tus programas sean más robustos, más legibles y más eficientes a la hora de hayar errores (depuración).

¡Espero haber sido de ayuda! Un saludo

Comment: No solo has sido de ayuda, sino que me has resuelto la duda. Muchísimas gracias. Un saludo.

Comment: Voy a continuar con el ejercicio, he creado un switch con un menu, a continuación del array, y hay dos opciones en las que tengo dudas. una es cambiar de posición los números introducidos. y otra; sacar el número más alto y más bajo, a ver si soy capaz. Por cierto, saludos desde Córdoba España.

Comment: ¡Me alegra que te haya servido! Ante cualquier duda, estoy dispuesto a ayudar. Un comentario más: podrías considerar llenar el arreglo con otro bucle de la forma: ```for(int i=0; i<arrayD.length; i++) { //Aquí dentro solicitar que ingrese el i-ésimo elemento del arreglo, con el do-while }```. Esto hará que tu código quede más compacto, menos repetitivo y más fácil de leer. Estos loops son muy útiles a la hora de trabajar con arreglos. Un saludo desde Córdoba, Argentina.

Comment: Gracias!!! máquina!! seguro que seguiré preguntando por aqui. Estoy empezando en esto.

Comment: Arkamai, si lleno el array con el bucle for, no puedo meter la restricción, de entre 0 y 100. Además me asalta otra duda, has puesto int=i; pero my array debe ser double

Comment: ¡Hola! La variable ```int i``` sólo está declarada para iterar en el loop ```for``` y hacer referencia a las posiciones en el arreglo (```arrayD[0], arrayD[1], arrayD[2]...```). Te dejo un enlace [aquí](https://pastebin.com/jB3hzXLc) con una solución que he desarrollado recién para tu problema, mostrándote paso a paso el funcionamiento de cada línea de código utilizando el loop ```for``` para llenar el arreglo de forma más compacta y legible. ¡Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Voy a por tu enlace. Gracias Máquina!!. Ya me dirás a que dirección te mando el jamón.

Comment: ¡De nada! Me alegra que te sirva. Ante cualquier duda, estoy dispuesto a ayudar.